# Parsing a complicated row creates extra columns

Tags: csvhelper

I've used CSVHelper successfully for many files over the years, and am familiar with CsvConfiguration.

My direct question is: How to use BadDataFound to do some conditional handling.

I have a source file that I need a little help with.  The file contains 148 columns and can be 100,000s rows. (We get this file every day from a partner, so this is an on-going issue, and is not just an isolated one-off)

So if you bear with me, I'm only going to paste a value that is tripping up the parser.

- "Close Time @ 3:00 P.M, 48" L x 40" W x 49" H, 38" L x 38" W x 20" H"

The CSV Parser tries its best to make sense of this but generates two columns:

- "Close Time @ 3:00 P.M, 48" L x 40" W x 49" H
- 38" L x 38" W x 20" H"

Notice the weird handling of opening and closing double quotes.

So in my 100,000 row file, this one line has an extra column.

There are other rows that trigger BadDataFound but that the parser can navigate and work out.

Examples of values that it successfully resolves to only one column:

- "Triple "R" Truck Parts "
- "KEEP SHRINK WRAP AND BLUE TAPE INTACT NON-STACKABLE  -----"APPOINTMENTS TO BE SCHEDULED VIA OPEN DOCK" "
- "150Lx3Wx3"H (3) / 150LX4Wx3 (2)"
- "** DO NOT STACK FREIGHT**.  FCFS - Handle with care. (GPS may show "east" Business Center Dr.  That is ok)"

The purpose of my code is to open these csv files, and use CsvHelper to write a copy of it, row by row, that gets rid of all the inner double quotes and commas so that SSIS can handle the file.

By it creating that extra column, it's throwing off the format for that row pattern.

```
CsvConfiguration csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
csvConfiguration.Delimiter = ",";
csvConfiguration.BadDataFound = LogBadData;
//csvConfiguration.BadDataFound = null;

csvConfiguration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
StringBuilder sbFile = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(workingFileName))
{
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfiguration))
    {
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            StringBuilder sbRow = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < csv.Parser.Record.Length; i++)
            {
                sbRow.Append("\"" + csv.GetField(i).Replace("\"", "").Replace(",","") + "\",");
            }

            sbFile.Append(sbRow.ToString().Substring(0, sbRow.ToString().Length - 1) + "\n");
        }



    }

}

File.WriteAllText(originalFileName, sbFile.ToString());
```

```
private static void LogBadData(BadDataFoundArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Field);
    Console.WriteLine(((CsvHelper.CsvParser)e.Context.Parser).Row.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I think what `CsvHelper` is doing is it sees `"Close Time @ 3:00 P.M, 48"` as opening and closing quotes and so it doesn't see the first comma as a delimiter.  It then sees `" W x 49"` as the next opening and closing quotes.  But when the next comma shows up at `H,` there is no opening quote to indicate that this comma is part of a field and not a delimiter.

Comment: Actually, it looks like after that first closing quote, all commas after that end up being delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your full data looks like, but if all of the fields are quoted `"field1","field2","field3","field4"`, you might be able to use something like `","` as your delimiter.

*Not sure why it cuts off the last 2 characters if I don't add a final line break.

```cs
void Main()
{
    CsvConfiguration csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    csvConfiguration.Delimiter = ",\"";
    csvConfiguration.BadDataFound = LogBadData;
    var workingFile = "\"150Lx3Wx3\"H (3) / 150LX4Wx3 (2)\",\"Triple \"R\" Truck Parts \",\"Close Time @ 3:00 P.M, 48\" L x 40\" W x 49\" H, 38\" L x 38\" W x 20\" H\"";
    workingFile += "\n\"KEEP SHRINK WRAP AND BLUE TAPE INTACT NON-STACKABLE -----\"APPOINTMENTS TO BE SCHEDULED VIA OPEN DOCK\" \",\"Item2\",\"Item3\"";
    workingFile += "\n";
    
    csvConfiguration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
    StringBuilder sbFile = new StringBuilder();
    var records = new List<dynamic>();
    using (var reader = new StringReader(workingFile))
    {
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfiguration))
        {
            records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();           
        }   
    }

    var writeConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
    { 
        ShouldQuote = args => true 
    };
    using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, writeConfig))
    {
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            var data = (IDictionary<string, object>)record;
            
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                var removeQuotes = ((string)item.Value).Replace("\"", "").Replace(",","");
                csv.WriteField(removeQuotes);
            }
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
private static void LogBadData(BadDataFoundArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Logging Field: " + e.Field);
    Console.WriteLine("Logging Row: " + ((CsvHelper.CsvParser)e.Context.Parser).Row.ToString());
}
```

Comment: A typical line is actually too long to paste here, it's over 1,000 characters.  I was removing characters from the end because they erroneously add a trailing column to every row.

Comment: It is going to be difficult to process the file if the quotes aren't escaped.  Does setting `csvConfiguration.Delimiter = ",\"";` work at all for you?  Does adding that result in the extra trailing columns?